# Synchronizing game between website and mobile app

Tags: unity-game-engine, synchronization, game-development

I want to develop a game where you go to the website and open the mobile app corresponding to it you scan the QR code on the website and synchronize the website and the app.
So the game will be on the website on the screen and the user will move their mobile phone and depending on how they move their hand the game on the website will react.
So the game will be developed with unity, is there a way to synchronize the website and app this way continuously without delay? and how?

I know the question is vague but it's not something within my expertise i just wanna know where to start my research, few keywords would help a lot. It's a new project in a field i haven't worked in before.
I want a game in a website to be in sync continuously with variables sent from a mobile app without delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very unspecific and open ended question, to which you cannot get a good answer based on how many open variables there are. So basically you want to make a game that runs on a website, and then want to make a mobile app that is able to communicate with the game.

The only way to do this is to use a server with a backend-api, which you can then fetch and push data from and to your webgame/app. Basically the server is your communication tool between webgame and app.

You need to make an app though which serves the mobile phone's orientation data to the server. How you do this and what kind of server software is best to use fully depends on what your skillset allows for, what the specific constraints are and what parts of the project already exist (what framework does the app use (react native for instance), what platform does the app run on...).

I can only tell you that this is by no means trivial. Let alone making an app is a ton of work, but writing a backend for the server, an app and a game that runs in a browser is a huge project! I would highly suggest you perform more research on server-client communication and app development, because the scope of this project is based on how you phrased your question probably far bigger than you imagined.

Comment: Thank you so much, i know the question was a bit vague but it's a new project and it's not in my expertise but i have one year to work on it but i simply didn't know where to start my research and now thanks to you at least i know what to look for exactly.

Comment: I would suggest you first make the webgame and get it to work with for instance mouse input, get it to a point where you only need to get the phone orientation data from somewhere and everything else runs fine in the browser. Then look into how you can make your app (have a look at Expo or follow some Android Native tutorials) and read the gyroscope data. As soon as you have that data you "only" need to get it to your webapp. Look into data-stream supporting backends (GraphQL is a good start), since you need to stream data constantly, not just do a few fetches every few minutes. Good luck :)